# How do build konqueror embedded? Is the project still alive?

Tags: browser

I have been looking at konqueror embedded. I looked at https://konqueror.org/embedded/ . The links are broken. Is this project still around and I wonder if anyone has used it? Vague question;

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it still exists and is alive, and the links do not seem dead for me.. Since the features are somewhat limited, you may want to look for something else.

Comment: I think qt-embedded may work better. Thanks for your help